# Storing per-server settings with Discord.py

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I am designing a bot to operate in many servers. I am using an SQLite database to keep track of the number of messages sent - per user per server.

The bot has some settings that I would like the moderators of these servers to change. Of course they should only be able to change the settings as to affect their server only.

How should I go about saving these settings preferences? I do not want to use a different database exclusively to store these settings in as it would require switching databases many times per second, which is - as far as I know - would be very slow, and is not its intended use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use a single table and use guild and user id as separate columns, selecting a single user from a single guild should be easy with that. Or you can create new tables for each guild but I wouldn't recommend doing that

Comment: @Ceres like I said, I have already decided I will be using a single table for all of the guilds. What I am asking for guidance with is how to store the bot settings that the moderators of each guild choose.

Comment: create a new table with guild id and the settings as json or separate columns?